# Iterative (non-recursive) implementation for aggregating Items of a List of List with arbitrary depth

Tags: java, recursion

Give an array such as:

```
[4, 2, [6, -4], 1, [3, [-13, 7], 2]]
```

I expect the see the number -15 as based on the depth of the array determines its multiplier e.g.

```
4 + 2 + 2(6 + -4) + 1 + 2(3 + 3(-13 + 7) + 2)
```

I have solved this recursively as below, But how would I achieve this iteratively?

This is the recursive solution:-

```
class Calculator {

    public static int calc(List<Object> array) {
        return calc(array, 1);
    }

    public static int calc(List<Object> array, int depth) {

        int sum = 0;
        for (Object object : array) {
            if (object instanceof ArrayList) {
                sum += calc((List<Object>) object, (depth + 1));
            } else {
                sum += (int) object;
            }
        }
        return depth * sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(4);
        list.add(2);
        List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<Object>();
        objs.add(6);
        objs.add(-4);
        list.add(objs);
        list.add(1);
        List<Object> objs2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        objs2.add(3);
        List<Object> objs3 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        objs3.add(-13);
        objs3.add(7);
        objs2.add(objs3);
        objs2.add(2);
        list.add(objs2);

        int res = Calculator.calc(list);

        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
Function<List<?>,Double> aggregator = list -> {
    Double value = 0.0;
    int depth = 1;
    double factor = 1;
    while(!list.isEmpty()) {
        List<?> remainingLevels = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Object item : list) {
            if(item instanceof Double) {
                // Add number
                value += factor * (Double)item;
            }
            else if(item instanceof List) {
                // Add elements, removing one level
                remainingLevels.addAll((List)item);
            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
        depth++;
        factor *= depth;
        list = remainingLevels;
    }
    return value;
};
```

Note: I like the recursive solution better!

Comment: Hi Christian, It's close but not quite right you see this way it multiplies each of the nested levels and adds them together which isn't the same as the recursive version. I get the sum of 3 with your algorithm but I get -15 with the recursive version.

Comment: OK. I see. But that just a change in the multiplier, which is depth! instead of depth, isn't it? - I made a corresponding change adding a separate factor.

Answer (score 2):

I like stacks, so here's an alternative solution that uses `Boolean`s as signals to increase or decrease depth.

```
int sum = 0, depth = 1, multiplier = 1;

Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.addAll(list);

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
  Object next = stack.pop();

  if (next instanceof Collection) {
    stack.add(false); //False means moving out
    stack.addAll((Collection) next);
    stack.add(true); //True means moving in
  } else if (next instanceof Boolean) {
    if ((Boolean) next)
      multiplier *= ++depth;
    else 
      multiplier /= depth--;
  } else sum += multiplier * (Integer) next;
}

return sum;
```